# Convert WMS Layers into Image is not Working but it's working for WFS

Tags: openlayers, wms, wfs

I'm using this method to convert the Map containing WMS layer to image later use that image in PDF. Everything is working fine for WFS layers but not with WMS layers.

```
function CaptureImage()
{
    map.once('postcompose', function(event) 
    {
               console.log(event);
               var canvas = event.context.canvas; 
               console.log(canvas); 
               if (navigator.msSaveBlob)
               {

                    navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png'); 

               } 
               else 
               {

                    canvas.toBlob(function(blob)
                    {  

                       var imgData= new Image(); 
                       imgData = canvas.toDataURL("png"); 

                       // Later I'm saving this image, but this is 
                       //                 workingfor 
                         //   WFS but not WMS Layers ;
                    });
               }

    });
}
```

Comment: Please do help this one out. I'm stuck for WMS Layers and it's working fine for WFS

Comment: If map variabel contains WFS then the image is generated otherwise nothing is generated in case of WMS

Comment: It might be due to tainted canvas.  If you are using an external WMS you will need `crossOrigin: 'Anonymous'` in the source options to access the canvas.

Comment: @Mike I have tried this one but still nothing is working. Thank you Mike

Comment: `Convert WMS Layers into Image` perhaps the issue centres around the fact <blink>that a WMS layer is already an image</blink>, so no conversion is required.